# Control in a 2D array

Tags: c#, for-loop, multidimensional-array, null, row

`[8, 8]` I have a 2-dimensional array creating rows and columns `[i, j]`.

I want to check if there is an object in a single row. For example, line 4 or line 1.

Comment: You have to check each index in row for null.  You could use : Enumerable.Range(0,8).Any(x => myArray[4,x] != null)

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

please also read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can run a `for` lopp and check.

```
int i = 0; //or 3 //here you can set the row number
bool exists = false;
int value = 4;
for(int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    if(array[i, j] == value)
    {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```